# System of User-Role and mapping with the other entities issue Spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, roles

I was trying to set up role-user system in my application using spring boot, spring security, Hibernate/JPA and JWT, so i've created two entites the first one:

*AppUser Entity:*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor

public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

*AppRole Entity:*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AppRole implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String roleName;

}
```

So everything goes well with the authentication of the different users (admin, client) using the jwt and spring security.

Before doing this system i created two entities: admin and client, but as you see now with this new implementation i have only one entity called AppUser (as admin and client have the same attributes).

The problem that i'm fascing now for this application is that the Admin should  manage some entities including 'Client' (it doesn't exist now), 'Projects', and
the Client should manage the Entity 'Intervention'.

Projects Entity :

```
 @Entity
 @Data
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @NoArgsConstructor
   public class Project implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String description;


      }
```

Following the old UML_Classes  Exemple : project + admin before the new implementation  :

[UML classe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb7Zx.png)

So how i'm going to implement the relation between those entities together? how i'm going to say that the entity AppUser will manage the entity Projects for exemple if he is an admin?

And so on

Please if there any useful link thank you for redirecting me to it , i didn't know what to search for to get what i want .

PS : this App is considered as an API Rest with spring boot as backend , and angular4 Client as front end , and in the Client i can get which user is authenticated and the roles he gets ,  i wantto know how i'm going to implement the other entities , for exemple Project that the admin manage , ORM Side so i can see all this entites in the database Mysql, should i add any roles or what ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plan is to have separate API endpoints for the admin functions and the user level functions then you can use Web security configuration to require authentication, and only allow particular roles to call those endpoints.
if the endpoints aren't separate then you can still use the spring authentication, but will have to get the current user and roles, and depending on what they are trying to do authorize your self or deny.[spring security java config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-authorize-requests)

***edit***
you can look into [Auditable](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-jpa-auditing-automatically-the-good-stuff) if you plan to do this professionally 
this will add user and timestamp info to your records

if you want to do this by hand add `String createdBy` or `owner` to the object.  then in [jpa interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) for the object add method definiton like `public List<Thing> getThingByOwner(String username);`

Comment: thank you for your answer first , what i'm planing to do is the second choice , i have an API Rest with spring boot as backend  , and angular4 Client as front end , and in the Client i can get which user is authenticated and the roles he gets , but this is not my issue , i wanted to know how i'm going to implement the other entities , for exemple Project that the admin manage , ORM Side , should i  add any roles or what  ?

Comment: @OneToMany/@ManyToOne from AppUser to Project. will store the user id on the project and give you access to a list of Projects that the specific  user owns.

Comment: ah i see , so there is no need of adding another entity called for exemple 'Permission' (as i saw now in some question ) , because in fact this would change the authentication code i used with spring security and JWT ,

Comment: spring security is going to control the type of user(admin,user,manager,root) which has access to particular resources (think urls/url endpoints) the OneToMany/ManyToOne shows relations of specific instances of those types. Bob(AppUser[admin_role]) owns MKUltra(project), Apollo(project).... if using JPA Repository you will need to create the queries that fetch projects based on the user though.

Comment: thank you so much for help , i appreciate that , and yes i'm using JPa repository , can you help with any exemple in any web site ? thank you in advance . (y)

Comment: Thank you for help i used the first method , this helped me so much  better !!

Comment: please what about the mapping of Admin And Client ? as there is now only one entity which is Appuser . i'm not supposed to do any thing about that right?

Comment: Can you give an example of an operation you want to preform on your data(including who is doing it) and how you want to restrict access. or a page where you want to display some data.

Comment: after the authentication of the admin he will get a page of the liste of all the clients in the database , so he can deletes any one , and also if any client came he can add it in the database , i didn't code this yet but this is the idea